# Do access modifiers affect extension methods?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, access-modifiers

I know this might be a stupid question, but I have to ask.
Do access modifiers (e.g. `protected` `private`) affect the visibility of extension methods? (whether they were on the class or on the method itself)

If so, can I show the extension method while hiding its class? (outside the assembly at least)

Answer (score 4):

`private` will hide the method from everybody, other than methods in the extension methods class (which is pointless).

`protected` means nothing for static methods.

You can make your class `Internal` so it will be hidden from other assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

From [How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311042.aspx):

> 1.Define a static class to contain the extension method.
>   The class must be **visible to client code**.
>
> 2.Implement the extension method as a static method with **at least the
>   same visibility as the containing class**.

So the containing class should be visible to the code, in which you're going to use the method. And the extension method itself should have at least the same visibility (not less).

---

Answering the question, *if one can hide the containing class but leave the extension method visible between assemblies*: **no you cannot**. You may try it yourself: just create a static class with a simple extension method (extending any class you like) in one assembly; make the class `internal` and the method `public`. Obviously you will not be able to use the method in any other assembly as well as the containing class in a whole. Though it does follow the second rule specified above, it does break the first, as the containg class **must** be visible to the code using the extension method.

Extension methods are the *syntactic sugar* for calling `static` methods. So imagine, if you wanted to call a simple static method having no access to the containing class. Would that work? Definitely not.